# Error while installing hadoop on ubuntu while hdfs namenode -formate command

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

Tryin to hdfs namenode -format but it says java denied permission!?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you able to run `java -version`? That says permission denied for Java not Hadoop. Also Hadoop doesn't support Java 9 yet

Answer (score 0):

This error might arise if you don´t start namenode as a hadoop user. Be sure not to run it as root and you can try this command:

```
/usr/hdp/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /usr/hdp/hadoop/conf start namenode
```

Comment: Can you check the access privileges on the HDFS directory /user, after logging in as the user hdfs and let me know your result ?

Comment: how to check the access

Comment: Use this command: ls -la /user or: ls -la /usr (depends on your system config). Please put your result here

Comment: /user doesn't exist on  Ubuntu